# Opening directory with emoji in Explorer

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, explorer

When I want to open a directory in Windows Explorer, I normally do this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"c:\some\path");
```

But I'm running into a problem with paths that contain emojis. For example, the following doesn't open the intended directory, but the "My Documents" library directory instead (probably as a default):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"c:\some\path\");
```

Is there something else I should be trying in order to get this to work as expected? It's probably some encoding issue, but even after experimenting with a few different string encodings I can't seem to get it to work.

I'm using .NET 4.0 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Your second sample works like a charme on my machine.

Comment: I think the folder name parameter name in 'System.Diagnostics.Process.Start' is not what you expect. Try to debug. On my machine it works without any changes or formatting. I also used .NET 4.0 on Win 8.1

Comment: I've verified the path (System.IO.Directory.Exists reports that the directory does indeed exist), and tried something as simple as "c:\" with no luck. Your comment made me wonder if something was up with the machine I was using, but I tested it on a second one in the same environment with the same results... Hm.